# Unable to install Powershell 4

Tags: windows-7, installation, 64-bit, powershell-v4.0

I am trying to install Windows Powershell 4.0. I use Windows 7 SP1 OS (x64 Bit).

I have downloaded & installed below packages already.

1. .NET Framework 4.5. (`NDP451-KB2858728-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe`)
2. Windows Management Framework 4.0. (`Windows6.1-KB2819745-x64-MultiPkg.msu`)

Both the packages got installed without giving any error however when I go to Powershell prompt & type the following:

```
powershell -version 4
```

It throws an error:

> Cannot start Windows PowerShell version 4 because it is not correctly installed.

Comment: Have you rebooted?  You don't get prompted, but part of the update will not be applied until you reboot.

Comment: yes, I rebooted after both installation.

Comment: You have installed .NET Framework 4.5.1. Have you tried installing 4.5? Maybe version 4.5.1 is not compatible with Powershell V4.
Check the currently running version of Powershell checking $PSVersiontable variable values.

Comment: Hi, Trinue, Bingo!! I have uninstalled .NET Framework 4.5.1 & Windows Management Framework 4.0 & installed .NET Framework 4.5 (dotnetfx45_full_x86_x64.exe) & re-installed WMF 4.0. And rebooted the computer. This time I saw Windows Update was running & it was updating OS. I knew that it was going well. Now I have Powershell 4.0 installed in my computer. If I type $PSVersionTable. It will return the result as: PS C:\Users\Admin> $PSVersionTable
----                           -----
PSVersion                      4.0

So, many many thanks for your help.

Comment: That should be posted as the answer. That's exactly what the solution is.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like is .NET Framework 4.5.1 not compatible with Powershell V4. So, I have uninstalled .NET Framework 4.5.1 and Windows Management Framework 4.0. Then I installed .NET Framework 4.5 (`dotnetfx45_full_x86_x64.exe`) & re-installed WMF 4.0. And rebooted the computer. This time I saw Windows Update was running & it was updating OS. I knew that it was going well.

Now I have PowerShell 4.0 installed in my computer. If I type `$PSVersionTable` it will return the result as:

```
PS C:\Users\Admin> $PSVersionTable

----        -----
PSVersion   4.0
```

Comment: Is there any verification from an authoritative source that there's a compatibility issue between .NET 4.5.1 and WMF 4.0? If so, it would be helpful to have a link added to the answer.

I was unable to duplicate the stated problem on Server 2008 R2 SP1. Installing NDP451-KB2858728-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe, then Windows6.1-KB2819745-x64-MultiPkg.msu, then performing a reboot resulted in a working PowerShell v4 installation.

Comment: It may have been [this issue](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2013/10/29/wmf-4-0-known-issue-partial-installation-without-net-framework-4-5.aspx), where the installation was simply incomplete somehow.